# FileParsing in C

Tags: c, file, io

So I have a text file filled with old onion links and its incredibly messy:

```
1   Dark web Link– Deep Web Links – Hidden Wiki     http://dwlonion3o3pjqsl.onion/  online
2   Darkode Reborn  http://darkodevasbv5yof.onion   online
3   Arm’s Factory   http://gunsfact2f6oz7cw.onion/  online
4   Dark Web Hackers Zone   http://darkzonebry27nxa.onion/  online
5   Raptor (Tor Chat Service)   http://raptortiabg7uyez.onion   online
```

*Each line looks like: `(int)\t(name)    (url)  (status)`
Since my C code tends to be pretty bad I wanted to improve it. I wrote a simple file parser which attempts to only take into account the url and status and would like to know if there are any ways of optimizing my code/improving the sort function since that's where I feel weakest:

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sorter.h"

#define onionLinksFile "onionlinks.txt"
#define output "sorted\\output.txt" //folder for output

int main() {

    FILE *file = fopen(onionLinksFile, "r");
    FILE *nFile = fopen(output, "w+");
    char line[256]; //allocate up to 256 chars for each line
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("> An error occured while attempting to open our file...");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) { //get each newline
        fprintf(nFile, sort(line)); //write our sorted data to our text file
        //printf(line);
    }
    
    fclose(file);
    fclose(nFile);

    return 0;
}
```

**sorter.h**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define delimter "\t" //our delimters
#define mDelimter "//"

char *sort(char line[256]) {
    int objCount = 0;
    int mObjCount = 0;
    
    char *token = strtok(line, delimter);
    while (token != NULL){ //attempt to split our string by tabs
        objCount++;

        if (objCount > 1){ //ignore the first number, don't care about that
            char *nToken = strtok(token, mDelimter);

            while (nToken != NULL){ //split the string again this time take everything past the //
                mObjCount++;
                if (mObjCount > 1){
                    return nToken;
                }
                nToken = strtok(NULL, "");
            }

        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "");
    }
}
```

And here is how the output looks:

```
/dwlonion3o3pjqsl.onion/    online
/darkodevasbv5yof.onion     online
/gunsfact2f6oz7cw.onion/    online
/darkzonebry27nxa.onion/    online
/raptortiabg7uyez.onion     online
/gurochanocizhuhg.onion/    offline
/6a3nny6zpg23dj7g.onion/    offline
```

Comment: `fprintf(nFile, sort(line)); ` i call it in the file output

Comment: Ah, I missed that. Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: I don't see `sort()` handling the order of items/tokens.

Comment: @greybeard yeah guess sorting wasn't really the right title, I'll remove sort, more meant cleaning up the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### General Observations

This program is great if you are the only user, but if it is for use by others here are some suggestions:

1. Allow users different ways to supply input and output files, rather than hard coding the name of the input and output files into the code.
2. Provide guidance for users if the enter the wrong thing.
3. Improve the error handling.

There are at least 3 ways that input and output can be handled by a program like this if the program is being executed from the command line:

1. File redirection
2. Command line arguments
3. The program prompts the user for the input and output file names.

It should be noted that one program can use all 3 methods to be the most flexible.

If the user is using file redirection than the input is coming in on `stdin` and the output is going out on `stdout`, errors should go to `stderr`. In this case the code

```
    FILE* file = stdin;
    FILE* nFile = stdout;
```

would be appropriate and the rest of the code would still work as it does now.

With command line arguments the program would have to use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` to get the file names.

While the code is checking that the input file can be opened for input, it is not checking that the output file can be opened for output and that can result in errors.

### Declare Variables When You Need Them

The variable `line` is defined at the top of `main()`, it would make the code more understandable and maintainable if `line` was declared immediately before the `while()` loop that drives the program. That would also make it easier to see that the `while loop` itself could be a function.

### Best Practice with Header Files

In C the `#include` preprocessor directive actually copies the included file into the file with the include directive, to prevent the code in the included file from being included there needs to be some mechanism for preventing the code from being included twice. There are 2 mechanisms for this, using include guards or using `#pragma once`. I prefer using include guards for 2 reasons, one it is more traditional (I am very old school) and the second is that while `#pragma once` is widely supported by many compilers it is not currently part of either the C standard or the C++ standard.

Include guards:

```
#ifndef FILE_NAME_H_
#define FILE_NAME_H_

... code ...

#endif  // !FILE_NAME_H_
```

Header files are generally used to provide the APIs or function prototypes from another C source file, it C it is very rare for a header file to contain executable code, because if the header file is included by multiple source files the functions within it exist in multiple places in the program and the program won't link.

### Enable All Compiler Warnings

When you compile your code use the -wall switch to enable all warnings, the `sort()` function currently has some logic issues in it that yields the following warning message:
`'sort': not all control paths return a value`. This warning message indicates that the function can return without providing a value and can indicate that there are serious problems in the code.

### Standard Symbolic Constants

Since the program includes `stdlib.h` there are 2 symbolic constants available that would make `main()` more readable, `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. These symbolic constants can be used in place of `return 0;` and `return 1;` in `main()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, exact feedback I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It would be more efficient to tokenise on '//' first, then tokenise the second array element on '\t'. This would avoid some string copying.